# why my flutter_background_fetch not work when app is terminate?

Tags: android, flutter, background-service, background-fetch

Hi I want my android app work in background even if the program completely close(terminate). I use the flutter_background_fetch for it. the notification show every 15 min correctly in app is open or go to background, But when I terminate app the background_fetch not work and not show the notification or do anything anymore.
here this my main file config:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask);
  initializeNotificationService();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void backgroundFetchHeadlessTask(HeadlessTask task) async {
  String taskId = task.taskId;
  bool isTimeout = task.timeout;
  if (isTimeout) {
    // This task has exceeded its allowed running-time.
    // You must stop what you're doing and immediately .finish(taskId)
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    return;
  }
  // Do your work here...
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}
```

and this is part of my controller body for background_fetch:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit

    super.onInit();
    startListeningNotificationEvents();
    initPlatformState();
  }
  
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    var status = await BackgroundFetch.configure(
        BackgroundFetchConfig(
          minimumFetchInterval: 15,
          forceAlarmManager: false,
          stopOnTerminate: false,
          startOnBoot: true,
          enableHeadless: true,
          requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
          requiresCharging: false,
          requiresStorageNotLow: false,
          requiresDeviceIdle: false,
          requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.NONE,

        ),
        _onBackgroundFetch,
        _onBackgroundFetchTimeout);
    BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask(TaskConfig(
        taskId: "test",
        delay: 1000,
        periodic: false,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        enableHeadless: true));
    BackgroundFetch.start();
  }

  void _onBackgroundFetchTimeout(String taskId) {
    //BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);


    }
    
      void _onBackgroundFetch(String taskId) async {
        if (taskId == "test") {
        

  random();
      createNotification();
    }
  }

}
```

in the document said if we want app work even after terminate, we should set the "stopOnTerminate" equals false. but still not working. how can fix this? please help.

Comment: It works after every 15mins. You can try to show a notification everytime a background task is successful.

Comment: I know. and when my app open or in background, the notifications show every 15 min. But when I close/terminate my app. no notifications show anymore.

Comment: What device are you using to test this?

Comment: in android studio for emulator I use "pixel 3a API 29". and for real device I use my own phone (xiaomi mi 9t pro)

Comment: Chinese devices such as Xiaomi, Redmi force stops the app when you terminate it from recent apps. You need to turn off force stopping of apps in one of your xiaomi apps. I am assuming you configured background service properly.

Comment: thank you. So is the anyway to manage this for every model of smart phone with programming? or every user should change own setting after install apps?

Comment: Every user has to do it on their own. There is no other way around it.

Comment: In the example in pub.dev the BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask); is after runApp

Comment: The task name is "flutter_background_fetch" and not "test"?

Comment: I change the task-id to test. and I don't think the problem is related to the name.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, what worked for me was using Workmanager. But running directly via the "Run" button in Android Studio, the callbackdispatcher only worked while the app was running (either in the foreground or background). When I closed the app, the task stopped working. However, when running via "flutter run" in the terminal, everything worked perfectly, even with the app closed in recent apps. So I recommend you test using "flutter run" first, if it doesn't work, try migrating from Background_Fetch to Workmanager and running via "flutter run" in the terminal.